# How can i draw some unicode characters like Chinese with OpenGL ES on Android platform

Tags: android, unicode, opengl-es, character

I currently developing a openGL ES 2D game,everything seems OK,but I need to show many Chinese characters in the game.

Answer (score 4):

Render the text using a combination of font rasterizer and unicode text layouter (for example FreeType and Pango) into a image, load this as texture and draw a quad with that texture.

Comment: I've tried and it works,thank u.But when I use something like FreeType it's ok with the emulator but negative with the real phone.